# Runtime Exception when running android uiAutomator

Tags: android, adb, android-uiautomator

i'm trying to automate the settings in my android device(input wifi password, create account display setting etc) using uiautomator.
But the behaviour of the code is quite unpridictable.
Sometimes it works totally fine, and other time it give the following exception on the same device, under the same conditions.

```
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.RuntimeException
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: LONGMsg=ChangeDisplaySetting    ## this is the name of the class
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

m quite unable to figure out the reason. Also the code is quite large, and i dont know, which part shall i copy here.

Please guide.
Also it would be helpful, if there exits some other way(like some other language) of doing the same. I was studying about python, but i'm not sure, if it would perform all the functions on user mode.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to try https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator. You can install it via `pip install uiautomator`, although it's under developing phase.